# Remove a line in image with FFT

Tags: python, image-processing, fft

I would like to remove vertical line from an image (an example). I took a 2D FFT and try to apply a mask to suppress the line. Nonethelesse the approch is not very efficient, because i lose an important part of information. How can i improve the treatment of FFT data? In FFT, how find the line?

[image]

My piece of code :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io
from skimage import data, img_as_float

Path_input = "C:\\Users\\yoyo\\Desktop\\"

imggray = img_as_float(data.astronaut())[:,:,0]*255 #opening image 
imggray[:,254:255] = 0 #force a vertical line
plt.imshow(imggray);plt.show()

imfft = np.fft.fft2(imggray)
mags = np.abs(np.fft.fftshift(imfft))
angles = np.angle(np.fft.fftshift(imfft))
visual = np.log(mags)
visual2 = (visual - visual.min()) / (visual.max() - visual.min())*255
plt.imshow(visual2);plt.show()

mask = io.imread(Path_input + 'mask_astro.png')[:,:,0]
mask = (mask < 100)
visual[mask] = np.mean(visual)

newmagsshift = np.exp(visual)
newffts = newmagsshift * np.exp(1j*angles)
newfft = np.fft.ifftshift(newffts)
imrev = np.fft.ifft2(newfft)
newim2 = np.abs(imrev).astype(np.float32)

plt.imshow(newim2);plt.show()
```

----- EDIT LATER ----

My "real" image:

[image]

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/36/5/1536312281-test.png

Comment: This just looks like a single column of black, could you not just test for this and then restitch the image? i.e, split the image in 2 without the line of black and then stitch

Comment: Thanks for your interest. It is an example, in my data there is a certain number of lines

Comment: Answers will generally only be as good as questions. Please use more representative images in your question. Also add any relevant information you have about how many lines you have, their spacing, what causes them, whether they are regular, whether they run the full height of the image, whether they are pure black, or just dark...

Comment: Wow. Your "real" images couldn't be farther from your astronaut example if they were on the moon. I think you need to be a lot more specific about which "line" you want to remove and what result you want to achieve.

Comment: And please post the source image by itself at real resolution if you want people to try and perhaps improve your code on it themselves.

Comment: XY problem alert: Is your _real_ problem that you want to detect the "elements to keep" despite the presence of the horizontal noise lines?

Comment: Done you can download picture

Answer (score 3):

Seems that width of that line is 1 pixel.

In this case you can get rid of line with horizontal **median filter** of size 3 (applied to narrow column)

**Edit**
With real picture we can see horizontal defective rows.

At first you can determine their Y-position, using edge-revealing filters like Sobel one.

Then apply median filter with mostly vertical aperture only to bad regions (or some kind of interpolation, as @SilverMonkey  noticed in comments).

Example of quick-made OpenCV treatment with `CV_MEDIAN filter size 11 x 3` applied twice with two ROI (region of interests) near y=110 and y=205. Note good compensation of the second defect, but the first one needs more work. Peculiarities are preserved.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you see my "real image", darkest parts of my image have to be kept and median filter could impact them

Comment: Left one is image to treat? But where is vertical line?

Comment: vertical line in my example and horizontal in real sorry

Comment: @MBo looks like you answered the original question but failed the "telepathy" test :-o

Comment: One-directional (here vertical) median filter should preserve objects with ObjSize>FilterSize. Experiment is needed. Note - there is no silver bullet. Any treatment will make image quality worse, and the main problem is to minimize distortions.

Comment: Also note: you can easily find y-coordinates of defected rows (using any edge-revealing filter like Sobel) and treat only narrow row, as I stated in answer.

Comment: Besides the median filter, the column could also be interpolated with other methods if necessary.